# Node Js - EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, open 'tmp'

Tags: node.js, multer

I've facing the issue on npm 6.13.1 version, when i upload a CSV file using the multer it's response an error "EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, open 'tmp'". I can not downgrade my npm version.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have that directory locked for some other package/program.

Check your global variables to see if there is anything like `export BABEL_CACHE_PATH=/tmp`

Reference: https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/388#issuecomment-466298734